# Изменение меню в 1С 8.2

Tags: 1с, меню

Добрый день!
 Вопрос по 1С версии 8.2. Есть ли какая-либо возможность в стандартной  полосе меню (тулбар не рассматриваем!) поменять порядок пунктов? Cтоит задача: меню **"Файл"** поставить в порядке следования после меню **Предприятие**?
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотя бы пример скриншотами дополнили, что ли. А то вообще ничего особо не понятно.

Comment: Кажется, такой возможности нет.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в конфигураторе свой интерфейс, расположите в нём любые пункты меню в желаемом вами порядке, далее два варианта: 
а). установите его в качестве основного для желаемых пользователей;
б). найдите среди других интерфейсов элемент со снятым флажком у свойства "Переключаемый", поставьте флажок, затем снимите этот флажок у вашего интерфейса, если он поставлен.